# How to cause one graph's filter to trigger several other graphs to be filtered too, in Tableau?

Tags: filtering, action, data-visualization, tableau-api

**Context:**

In tableau, I have a dashboard which contains four different sheets, each of which come from different data sources.  However, they all have the same field *Field* in common.  Currently, when I want to filter each graph from the different data sources in the dashboard, I have to use the dropdown box to filter each one by *Field* individually.  This is inefficient because each time I filter one graph, I also need to filter for the other three graphs.  And since I am using a live connection to a data server, each time that I filter a graph, I need to wait ~30 seconds, totaling a ~2 minute wait for all four graphs.

**Question:**

Is there a way in Tableau that I can cause the filter for one graph to trigger the same filter on the same field on the other three graphs?  If so, how would I do this?

**What I have tried:**

So far, I have tried exploring the *Dashboard > Actions* menu, but have not been able to figure out how to achieve this. I have also read through the [Tableau Online Help](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#actions.html%3FTocPath%3DDo%2520More%2520with%2520Views%7CActions%7C_____0) to no avail.

Thank you in advance for any help that you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tableau 9, filters can only affect one data source, so you need to do a little more work to accomplish your goal. The options are:

- Use a parameter instead of showing a filter control on your dashboard. Parameters are associated with the workbook, not a specific data source. Then reference that parameter inside a calculated field in each data source you wish to impact. Put the calculated fields on the filter shelves of the worksheets you wish to control. This is a very flexible approach, but parameters can only take a single value at a time -- so it doesn't allow multiple selection in your filter unless you define a parameter value to represent specific combinations.
- Use a dashboard filter action so that actions on one worksheet trigger filters on other worksheets. This approach allows multiple selection. I recommend specifying "Selected Fields" in the Target Filter section when defining filter actions if there is any confusion. Pay attention to both the field names and data source names when setting them up.

In Tableau 10, you will be able to have filters affect related data sources.

Comment: After your suggestion to use parameters, I was looking for a detailed guide on how to do it.  I came across [this](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2012/7/filtering-parameters-18326) which worked great.  Thanks!